# In MSVC there are such things as MFC custom controls (design time), is there a such thing as a win32 custom control?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

In microsoft visual c++ (visual studio) one can create design time controls that you drag and drop on to your dialogs using MFC.

For example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521/Creating-Custom-Controls

[image: custom control]

My question is: can one develop win32 custom controls that you can drag and drop onto your dialog at design time, without using MFC?  Or with win32 programming are you stuck with the controls that win32 offers you (i.e. edit, listbox, checkbox, etc.).

Does the visual studio c++ ide only allow you to create mfc custom controls at design time, and with win32 you must create custom controls at run time?

Comment: You can add a "custom control" to a dialog in Win32 as well, but the dialog editor doesn't know anything about it. You just get a generic template where you can specify the basic parameters (window class, styles, etc). As long as the class is registered the control will be created when the dialog is.

Comment: @David: The [DLGITEMTEMPLATEEX structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645389.aspx) can specify arbitrary window class names, and provide arbitrary initialization data. They are specified using the generic `CONTROL` keyword in the [DIALOGEX resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381002.aspx). As Jonathan points out, this will show up as a generic template at design time, though. An exception are ActiveX controls, that can implement a design time representation for use by the resource editor.

Answer (score -1):

It is true you are more limited as for having the option to select a control from the Toolbox, which is easy with MFC. However, you can create or use custom controls for a Win32 project, and yet, such controls will be fancy and professionally looking project that doesn’t support MFC.
These custom controls will be either static libraries, DLLs or just c++ classes. 
[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559385/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-The-Basics) is an example.

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about the design time aspect of custom controls. This is possible with ActiveX controls only. You cannot ship ActiveX controls as static libraries, or get design time support when shipping source code. The link isn't helpful. It misses to address the question just as much.

Comment: Custom controls don’t have to be based on ActiveX. There are other ways, as in the example I gave.

Comment: Correct. Custom controls need not be ActiveX controls. Yet only ActiveX controls provide design-time support in Visual Studio's graphical resource editor. That's what the OP is asking about. This answer does not address this.

Comment: 1. What about VS extensions? 2. The OP is asking about MFC Vs. Win32 and I would argue, you can use Custom Controls at design time without using MFC.

Comment: `1` Visual Studio extensibility allows you to provide a *lot* of functionality. Design-time support for straight Windows API custom controls is not one of those. `2` [My comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086821/in-msvc-there-are-such-things-as-mfc-custom-controls-design-time-is-there-a-s/57531125#comment46407993_29086821) above explains, how much design-time support you can get for custom controls. There is no support at all for control customization. This is in contrast to ActiveX controls.

Comment: I updated my answer. When it comes to design time and the Visual Studio “toolbox”, you are right, however it is important to put emphasis on the fact that amazing UI elements can be developed using just Win32 (probably better looking and functioning than MFC can provide).

Comment: If the question is: *"Is it possible to get design-time support for custom controls written against the Windows API?"*, then you need not put emphasis on promoting something, that does not provide. Not sure what point you are trying to get across.

Comment: @IInspectable because of Visual Studio extendability and because that is part of the question

Comment: We are going in circles. Let's bail out. The **only** way to get design-time support in Visual Studio's graphical resource editor is by using ActiveX controls. There's really nothing more to add. If you ignore this, and feel like you need to emphasize something else, you are failing to address the question. I'm not going to put any more time into this.